# How do I add a class to a datetime_select in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

Here is the select from with multiple selects, im unsure how to target each on one the selects in this way.

```
<%= datetime_select 'date', :date, start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: 1.year.from_now.year, :minute_step => 10%>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it in [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-datetime_select)

```
datetime_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})

<%= datetime_select 'date', :date, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: 1.year.from_now.year, :minute_step => 10}, {class: 'your-class'} %>
```

Comment: do you know of a way to target each date, year, minute etc within this?